# How to tell if SimpLite is running?

Tags: installation, instant-messaging

I installed SimpLite for Pidgin (IM) on Ubuntu 12.10. After installation I am wondering how to see whether SimpLite is up and running?

For installation for SimpLite see [Installing SIMP](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=756706)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if you see it running in

```
ps -ef | grep -i simp
```

Comment: 2384  2272  0 15:45 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto -i simp <br/> <br/> Does this mean it is running?

Comment: No, that one is the process that you just ran. So no, it's not running